# Drupal Commerce: Prices on Variations not displayed when selecting a variation

Tags: ajax, commerce

I am using [Drupal Commerce Kickstart 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

When a user selects a value from the size drop down (variation), the price and other attributes do not update on the product display. I need to have something similar to this -> http://demo.commerceguys.com/ck/storage-devices/commerce-guys-usb-key. You'll see that when you select a memory size for the USB product the price will change.

Is this a built in feature for Drupal Kickstart or something they built through a custom module?

I have a product variation with a product attribute of Size (a user can select which size they want). I have product details such as SKU, Price, and Package.

I also have a product display set up by default, which displays my product variations as my Add to Cart form.

In the following picture you will see that even though I have 5 oz. selected all the details displayed are for the 10 oz. variation. 
[image: variation details not updating]

I need to know how to update these details based on which variation the user selects.

Any help on this is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work out of the box. There was a JQuery version conflict that was causing javascript errors.